#  Export struct defined in winbase.h with ATL's IDL 

Tags: windows-ce, atl, idl, windows-mobile-6.5

This is my method defined in IDL:

```
[id(3), helpstring("method GetBatteryStatus")] 
HRESULT GetBatteryStatus([out,retval] SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_EX2* batteryStatus);
```

The `SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_EX2` is a struct defined in `winbase.h`, and this project is a ATLSmartPhone Project, the `winbase.h` is from Microsoft's SDK.

When I compile the project the error are :

```
error MIDL2025 : syntax error : expecting a type specification near "SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_EX2"
```

If I add `import "winbase.h"` to the top of the IDL file, the error will be:

```
error MIDL2003 : redefinition : size_t; error MIDL2003 : redefinition : _LARGE_INTEGER;.....
```

Then if I add the typedef in in IDL:

```
typedef[public,uuid(37DE998A-6787-415a-A191-861C315D1248),helpstring("Power Status")]
struct _SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_EX2 {
  ...
  ...
} SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_EX2;
```

The error will be:

```
error C2011: '_SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_EX2' : 'struct' type redefinition.
```

So how can I export the `SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_EX2` struct which was defined in `winbase.h` with IDL?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the `IDL` version of the `SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_EX2` in the separate `IDL` file and import it for `MIDL` only:

```
cpp_quote("#if 0")
import "fake.idl";
cpp_quote("#else")
cpp_quote("#include <orginial_header>")
cpp_quote("#endif")
```